# Add an analyze function of an existing TYPE for Postgres

Tags: postgresql

From
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtype.html
, I find that I could create a type with a analyze function by
`[ , ANALYZE = analyze_function ]`, to collect statistical information.

I have an existing type, for example, TypeA, and have a table storing TypeA data. Unfortunately, it don't have the analyze function... I don't want to change the table, however I still want to add an analyze function to TypeA. Are there any way to do this?

Comment: A) I hope you are not still using 9.1, it is coming up on 4 years past EOL. B) The type may be still be analyzed. From the link: " By default, ANALYZE will attempt to gather statistics using the type's "equals" and "less-than" operators, if there is a default b-tree operator class for the type." So you will need to show what you type definition is?

Comment: Is it a type written in C?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  a type that wrap a PostGIS geometry and many other things... Cannot be shown here but anyway it's a complex type and a default analyze function is not enough

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PostgreSQL v13 on you can set the type analyze function with a simple `ALTER TYPE`:

```
ALTER TYPE typeschema.typename SET (ANALYZE = funcname);
```

Before that, you'll have to mess with the system catalogs:

```
UPDATE pg_type SET typanalyze = 'funcname'::regproc
WHERE typname = 'typename'
  AND typnamespace = 'typeschema'::regnamespace;
```

This should be safe enough.